# XSL code to rename the prefix without disturbing the attributes

Tags: xslt

I have given below the XSL codes i have tried and the part of input and output codes.If I use  XSL1 to rename the namespace prefix values in the xml tags , unfortunately it collapses the attribute values and if I use XSL2 attributes are getting created a separate nodes. Can someone pls help to write an XSL to rename the prefixes but to keep the attributes in the same node.

XSL 1:​

```
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ns0:*">
<xsl:element name="ubl:{local-name()}" namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

XSL2:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy></xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="@*">
 <xsl:element name="{name()}">
 <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ns0:*">
<xsl:element name="ubl:{local-name()}" namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Input:

```
<ns5:LegalMonetaryTotal>
  <ns2:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">35.38</ns2:LineExtensionAmount>
  <ns2:TaxExclusiveAmount currencyID="EUR">35.38</ns2:TaxExclusiveAmount>
  <ns2:TaxInclusiveAmount currencyID="EUR">37.5</ns2:TaxInclusiveAmount>
  <ns2:PrepaidAmount currencyID="EUR">37.5</ns2:PrepaidAmount>
  <ns2:PayableAmount currencyID="EUR">0.00</ns2:PayableAmount>
</ns5:LegalMonetaryTotal>
```

Output1:

```
<cac:LegalMonetaryTotal >
  <cbc:LineExtensionAmount >EUR35.38</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
  <cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount >EUR35.38</cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount>
  <cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount >EUR37.5</cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount>
  <cbc:PrepaidAmount >EUR37.5</cbc:PrepaidAmount>
  <cbc:PayableAmount >EUR0.00</cbc:PayableAmount>
</cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
```

Output2:

```
<cac:LegalMonetaryTotal >
  <cbc:LineExtensionAmount >
    <currencyID>EUR</currencyID>
    35.38
  </cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
  <cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount >
    <currencyID>EUR</currencyID>
    35.38
  </cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount>
  <cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount >
    <currencyID>EUR</currencyID>
    37.5
  </cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount>
  <cbc:PrepaidAmount >
    <currencyID>EUR</currencyID>
    37.5
  </cbc:PrepaidAmount>
  <cbc:PayableAmount>
    <currencyID>EUR</currencyID>
    0.00
  </cbc:PayableAmount>
</cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
```

But Expected output is: I have tried multiple options guys. Please help me to get the below format.

```
<cbc:LegalMonetaryTotal>
  <cac:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">35.38</cac:LineExtensionAmount>
  <cac:TaxExclusiveAmount currencyID="EUR">35.38</cac:TaxExclusiveAmount>
  <cac:TaxInclusiveAmount currencyID="EUR">37.5</cac:TaxInclusiveAmount>
  <cac:PrepaidAmount currencyID="EUR">37.5</cac:PrepaidAmount>
  <cac:PayableAmount currencyID="EUR">0.00</cac:PayableAmount>
</cbc:LegalMonetaryTotal>
```

Regards,

Indu

Comment: Please show minimal but complete sample, it is rather pointless to talk about a namespace related problem without showing the exact namespace declarations.

Comment: In addition to Martin comment, roughly, if both the input `ns5` and the expected `cbc` prefixes point to the same namespace (and same remark for `ns2/cac`), then the two input and expected XML are **identical**. No need to rename the prefixes, any XML software interprets the namespaces corresponding to the prefixes, not the prefixes themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your first stylesheet does not output any attributes is that you have no template that handles attributes. Therefore, the instruction:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
```

does not do anything for attributes.

Try changing your first template:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to the standard *[identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT)* template:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

That will probably make it work. I say *probably*, because your stylesheet does not fit your input nor the expected output. Your stylesheet looks for:

```
<xsl:template match="ns0:*">
```

but your input has no elements with a `ns0` prefix. And your stylesheet outputs a `ubl` prefix, while your expected output uses `cbc` and `cac` prefixes. And - as already mentioned in the comments to your question - all these prefixes need to be bound to namespaces in order for the input and the input to be well-formed XML documents.

Comment: Hi Michael,Yes I should have added the full snippet for you to get an idea. I have used below snippet and repeated for all the namespace prefixes ns0,ns1,ns2,ns3,ns4,ns5.

Comment: <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/><xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy> <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
         </xsl:copy> </xsl:template><xsl:template match="ns0:*">
      <xsl:element name="ubl:{local-name()}" namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"> <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/> </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template> <xsl:template match="@ns0:*"><xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute></xsl:template>

Comment: Please don't post code  in comments - it's unreadable. Either edit your question or post a new one.